# Как изменить текст элемента на свой через Tampermonkey?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. Я хотел сделать перевод сайта на русский через Tampermonkey, как это реализовать? Пробовал всяко, но что-то не получается

```js
// ==UserScript==
// @name         TaORuS by LoyrLino
// @namespace    https://world.taobao.com
// @version      0.0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       LoyrLino
// @match        *https://world.taobao.com*
// @exclude      *://taobao.com*
// @grant        none
// ==/UserScript==


    $( "div.title text-16" ).replaceWith( "<h2>New heading</h2>" );
    document.body.innerHTML = document.body.innerHTML.replace('商品分类', 'AndryMan');

var b = document.getElementsByClassName("block2")[0],
    i = b.innerHTML;
b.className = "block3";
alert(i);
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Замените скриншот на код.

Comment: Заменил на код.

Comment: @Other поможете?

Answer (score 1):

1. На сайте нет жуквери, так что `$(...).replaceWith(...)` работать не будут.
2. Если нужно найти элемент с двумя классами, их нужно писать так: `div.title.text-16` (без пробелов, иначе будет трактоваться как: "Найди мне `div` с классом `title` и **в нём** найди элемент с классом `text-16`).
3. Заменять весь `body.innerHTML` - это одна из худших практик, которую можно придумать. Заменяйте точечно.
4. Элементов с классом `block2` на странице нет.

Примерно так.